# Complicated array grouping

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I need your help with this array, i really don't know how to sort this:

```
[{userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 1, to: 6}, 
{userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 7, to: 15}, 
{userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 172, to: 181},
{userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 182, to: 190}]
```

into that:

```
[{userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 1, to: 15},
{userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 172, to: 190}]
```

Could you help me? It can be lodash or underscore, i tried with both and really can't solve this problem

Comment: That does not look like sorting to me. Looks like combining items.

Comment: It is not sorting that you want. Furthermore; on what condition do you group the from / to fields as the userId is the same for all.

Comment: are thy values non overlapping and in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the `userId` and if the same, the check if the items are in order, then change `to` property.

It works for sorted items. If not sorted, you clould apply a sort before.

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.userId.localeCompare(b.userId) || a.from - b.from;
});
```

```js
var data = [{ userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 1, to: 6}, { userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 7, to: 15 }, { userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 172, to: 181 }, { userId: "3t5bsFB4PJmA3oTnm", from: 182, to: 190 }],
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var last = r[r.length - 1] || {};
        if (last.userId === a.userId && last.to + 1 === a.from) {
            last.to = a.to;
        } else {
            r.push({ userId: a.userId, from: a.from, to: a.to });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```